# Android - HTTPURLConnection fails while posting multiple inputs

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am trying to post 5 string values and an image to php server by using `HTTPURLConnection`. Getting Response code as 200 and Response message as OK but actual response after posting is not getting. Below is the code i am using:

```
  public int sendRprtWithImageToServer(String getImagePath, String strEmailList){

      String upLoadServerUri = "My URL";
      String fileName = getImagePath;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
      int serverResponseCode = 0;

      File sourceFile = new File(getImagePath);
      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
       Log.e("Huzza", "Source File Does not exist");
       return 0;
      }
      try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
       FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
       URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
       conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
       conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
       conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
       conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
       conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
       conn.setRequestProperty("stringkey1", stringvalue1);
       conn.setRequestProperty("stringkey2", stringvalue2);
       conn.setRequestProperty("stringkey3", stringvalue3);
       conn.setRequestProperty("stringkey4", stringvalue4);
       conn.setRequestProperty("stringkey5", stringvalue5);
       conn.setRequestProperty("stringkey6", fileName);
       dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"stringkey1\";filename=\""+ stringvalue1 + "\"" + lineEnd);
       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"stringkey2\";filename=\""+ stringvalue2 + "\"" + lineEnd);
       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"stringkey3\";filename=\""+ stringvalue3 + "\"" + lineEnd);
       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"stringkey4\";filename=\""+ stringvalue4 + "\"" + lineEnd);
       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"stringkey5\";filename=\""+ stringvalue5 + "\"" + lineEnd);
       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"stringkey6\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

       bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size
       Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

       bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
       buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

       // read file and write it into form...
       bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

       while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

       // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
       InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

       int ch;
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
       while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
           sb.append((char) ch);
       }
       Log.d("String response ", sb.toString());
       // Responses from the server (code and message)
       serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
       String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
       Log.i("Upload file to server", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
       // close streams
       Log.i("Upload file to server", fileName + " File is written");
       fileInputStream.close();
       dos.flush();
       dos.close();
      } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
    //this block will give the response of upload link
      try {
       BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
         .getInputStream()));
       String line;
       while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.i("Huzza", "RES Message: " + line);
       }
       rd.close();
      } catch (IOException ioex) {
       Log.e("Huzza", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
      }
      return serverResponseCode;  // like 200 (Ok)


}
```

Can anyone help me how to pass multiple parameters for `HTTPURLConnection`

Comment: @AkhileshSk first 5 are string values and 6th one is file.... Do you know how to change `conn.setRequestProperty` and `dos.writeBytes`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use filebody to get file attach itself inside and 5 other string should be embedded inside multipart

```
public JSONObject file_upload1(String URL, String userid, String topic_id,
        String topicname, String filelist, List<String> taglist,
        String textComment, String textLink) {
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

        FileBody bin = null;
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);


            File file = new File(filelist);
            System.out.println("file name" + filelist.get(i));


            try {
                bin = new FileBody(file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            reqEntity.addPart("post_data" + i, bin);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < taglist.size(); i++) {
            reqEntity.addPart("dtype" + i, new StringBody(taglist.get(i)));
        }

        reqEntity.addPart("tag", new StringBody("savetopicactivities"));
        reqEntity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody(userid));
        reqEntity.addPart("text", new StringBody(textComment));
        reqEntity.addPart("count",
                new StringBody(String.valueOf(taglist.size())));
        reqEntity.addPart("topic_id", new StringBody(topic_id));
        reqEntity.addPart("topic_name", new StringBody(topicname));
        reqEntity.addPart("link", new StringBody(textLink));

        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        json = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("json   " + json);
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        is.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

Comment: for that you need to import jar files signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar , apache-mime4j-0.6.jar , httpmime-4.2.1.jar ,signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar , signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar .These jar are very easy to find out from google